# Where to find definitive list of assemblies that ship with .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, gac

I am trying to work out where various assemblies in my GAC have come from.

Would be useful if I could find a defintive list somewhere (for any given version of the framework), but so far can only find the list of assemblies that are included in the [.NET Client Profile.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462634.aspx)

Comment: Unanswerable.  The GAC is *not* exclusive to the framework.

Comment: I did not claim the GAC was exclusive to the framework...I mentioned the GAC in the context of wondering whether a given GAC assembly originated from the .net fx

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that what you're looking for can be found here:

```
 Directory of C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\RedistList

10/12/2010  03:47 PM              .
10/12/2010  03:47 PM              ..
03/18/2010  12:19 PM            15,715 AssemblyList_4_client.xml
03/18/2010  03:47 PM             8,220 AssemblyList_4_extended.xml
               2 File(s)         23,935 bytes
```

I would also look in

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0
```

Note that on a 64-bit install you should look in `Program Files (x86)`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the code shown in this could help
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=535

```
var filtered = assemb
.Where(x => x.Assembly.FullName.Contains("Version=4.0.0.0"))
.GroupBy(a => a.Name.Length)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: I think this only shows you assemblies loaded into your AppDomain.